# Does there exist a "Margolis-type" definition of equivariant cellular towers?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category

I am interested in cellular towers in the equivariant stable homotopy category $SH_G$ corresponding to a compact Lie group along with a complete universe for it.

Note here that a cellular tower for an object $M$ of $SH_G$ "should be" a filtration of $M$ by certain "subobjects" $M_i$ such that $M$ equals the homotopy colimit of $M_i$, the $n$th "quotient"  of the filtration is a bouquet of $G$-spheres of dimension $n$ (i.e., it is of the form $O_{n+}\wedge S^n$, where $O_n=\sqcup G/H_n^j$), and the homotopy limit of $M_i$ is zero in a certain sense. The latter condition appears to be the most difficult to deal with. In section 6.3 of the book "Spectra and the Steenrod Algebra" by  H.R. Margolis (where the "ordinary" stable homotopy category is treated, i.e., $G$ is trivial) this condition is formulated in terms of singular homology. On the other hand, in the book "Equivariant Stable Homotopy Theory" (https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/equi.pdf) only equivariant $G$-CW-spectra are considered. These may be considered as "models" for cellular towers, and their definition involves two filtrations.

So my question is: which definitions of cellular towers, $G$-CW-spectra, and related matters currently exist? I would prefer to have some definition in terms of the homotopy category (similar to the one given by Margolis). Also, I wonder where the "triangulated" properties of  $G$-CW-spectra are treated in detail.

Comment: Mark Hovey told me part of his goal with the monograph "Axiomatic stable homotopy theory" was to generalize Margolis's work. That monograph contains the setting you're asking about towards the end, in the last chapter. Tomorrow, if this still has no answer, I'll try to see if there's anything about explicit cellular towers.

Comment: Dear David; it appears that the only place in "Axiomatic stable homotopy theory" where cellular towers are mentioned is Proposition 7.1.2. However, the authors do not want to consider towers that are not bounded below; so they assume that the corresponding "homotopy groups" of an object vanish in degrees less than $k$.

Comment: I remembered where I'd seen this in the HPS monograph: It's Remark 2.2.5 that characterizes homotopy colimits, and your case corresponds to taking the $\{X_i\}$ to be the $O_{n+} \wedge S^n$. That these objects $O_{n+} \wedge S^n$ generate the equivariant stable homotopy category is the content of Theorem 9.4.3 in HPS.

Comment: Note that my main problem is the dealing with certain homotopy limits and not colimits.:) Yes,  Theorem 9.4.3 in HPS is interesting for me; yet it does not answer my question.